# How can I create a value centred sliding window in polars?

Tags: python-polars, windowed

In python I wrote a generator which returns what I call a 'value-centred' sliding window over the data.  For example, given the data:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

which when called like this produces:

```
   for index, window in sliding_window_iter(v, 3):
        print("value={} window={}".format(v[index], window))

    value=1 window=[1, 2, 3]
    value=2 window=[1, 2, 3]
    value=3 window=[2, 3, 4]
    value=4 window=[3, 4, 5]
    value=5 window=[4, 5, 6]
    value=6 window=[5, 6, 7]
    value=7 window=[6, 7, 8]
    value=8 window=[7, 8, 9]
    value=9 window=[8, 9, 10]
    value=10 window=[8, 9, 10]
```

As you can see it produces a tuple as output: `(centre_value, window)`

How might I re-implement this in polars?

The closest thing to it would be:

`df.group_by_dynamic` with `include_boundaries=True` but obviously it's not the same.

I'd prefer an implementation that is stream oriented (i.e.: which does not require reading in all the data into memory).

Answer (score 2):

*TLDR.* For a window of size `2*k + 1` the following can be used.

```py
(
    df
    .rolling(
        index_column=pl.int_range(pl.len()).alias("index"),
        period=f"{2*k+1}i"
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col("val")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            pl.int_range(pl.len()) >= k
        ).then(
            pl.col("val").shift(-k)
        )
        .forward_fill().backward_fill()
    )
)
```

## Explanation

In sounds like the *value-centered sliding window* is defined only for odd window sizes (such that there is a unique *center*). In the following, we therefore consider window sizes of the form `window_size = 2*k + 1` for some positive `k`.

**Example data.**

```py
import polars as pl

k = 1

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "val": list(range(6))
})
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌─────┐
│ val │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
│ 5   │
└─────┘
```

Indeed, shifting the result of [`polars.DataFrame.rolling`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html)  with a `period = 2*k + 1` by `-k`mostly does the correct thing here.

```py
(
    df
    .rolling(
        index_column=pl.int_range(pl.len()).alias("index"),
        period=f"{2*k+1}i"
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col("val")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("val").shift(-k)
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ val       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [0, 1]    │ # wrong
│ 1     ┆ [0, 1, 2] │ # correct
│ 2     ┆ [1, 2, 3] │ # correct
│ 3     ┆ [2, 3, 4] │ # correct
│ 4     ┆ [3, 4, 5] │ # correct
│ 5     ┆ null      │ # wrong
└───────┴───────────┘
```

*Note.* I visualise the result by aggregating the window elements into a list, but really any aggregation could be used.

This is correct except for

- the first `k` rows, where the window does not contain enough elements, and
- the last `k` rows, which are missing after the shift.

Now, the idea is to use a simple `pl.when().then()` construct to also overwrite the first `k` rows with `None`. This way, the first and last `k` rows are missing.

Finally, we can use a forward/backward fill to fill the missing rows with the desired values.

```py
(
    df
    .rolling(
        index_column=pl.int_range(pl.len()).alias("index"),
        period=f"{2*k+1}i"
    )
    .agg(
        pl.col("val")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            pl.int_range(pl.len()) >= k
        ).then(
            pl.col("val").shift(-k)
        )
        .forward_fill().backward_fill()
    )
)
```

*Note.* The initial shift from before was moved inside the `pl.when().then()` construct. It would've also been possible to set the `offset` parameter of `pl.DataFrame.rolling` to `-k-1`. However, then we'd need to set the first *and* last `k` rows of the column to `None`.

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ val       │
│ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [0, 1, 2] │
│ 1     ┆ [0, 1, 2] │
│ 2     ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 3     ┆ [2, 3, 4] │
│ 4     ┆ [3, 4, 5] │
│ 5     ┆ [3, 4, 5] │
└───────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great and is really close.  But in my original implementation, the windowing fn returned a list of tuples, where the first element was the index of the element at the centre of the window.

Comment: @pnadeau So the `index` column in my answer doesn't work? You can always get the center value of the `val` column using `.with_columns(pl.col("val").list.get(k).alias("center"))`. Or is it that you are specifically looking for a column that stores *tuples*?

Comment: I don't really mind if it stores tuples, I just want to be able to get the element and the window.  The 'centre' element is only at the centre for the windows where there is enough room.  For the initial windows, the element in question is not at the centre (see `value=1` value=10` in the original question).

Comment: @pnadeau I see. In this case, you can add `pl.col("val").last().alias("center")` in the call of `pl.DataFrame.agg`. Please lmk if this gives the expected result.

Comment: Yes this did work.  Will do more testing, but it looks good.

Comment: Yup, it's good, if you update the answer then I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.